# Google Sheets Data Validation Warnings When Using Relative Paths with Filter View

Tags: arrays, validation, google-sheets, filter, dropdown

[Update 1] This appears to only happen when using a filter view

[Update 2] Link to sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15eIm2ldEvgcoImTxB6Ik7c8AEJ3bhPzttpRUszN_Jvc/edit?usp=sharing

I have a sheet where I need to use data validation to create dropdown lists that change by row. The dropdown list options are maintained using cells on the same row (i.e. row x's options are also maintained on row x). I'm using "Data Validation -> List from a range" with the following formula for the cell on row 3:

```
=Options!$B3:$E3
```

As you notice, I'm keeping the row path relative so that the dropdown list changes from row to row. The formula for the cell on row 4 is therefore:

```
=Options!$B4:$E4
```

This works correctly in terms of what appears in the dropdown lists. The problem is that Google Sheets complains about the inputs I select saying the input data is invalid (even if I select it from the dropdown list). There are no circular dependencies between the validated cells and the ranges containing the dropdown list items.

The only way the warnings go away is if I use absolute paths (i.e. $B$2:$E$2). However, this makes it difficult to copy/paste the cell and data validation to other rows.

Any idea how I can fix this?

The data is supposed to be text, and I've formatted both the ranges of items and the column where I'm using data validation as plain text.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet

Comment: Actually, I just realized this ONLY happens when in "filter view" and the sorting of items in the table has changed. The dropdowns work right because of the way it's setup, but something throws off the data validation warnings. Here's a sample sheet that demonstrates this:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15eIm2ldEvgcoImTxB6Ik7c8AEJ3bhPzttpRUszN_Jvc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use filter view with sorting capabilities...

right now you are doing dropdowns from F:H range which is dynamically based on E column. what you need to do is to make it static like J:M range and then create a dropdown from K:M. this way if you sort or filter the A column the data validation won't throw any errors:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! This is what I was missing. For some reason got myself thinking that I needed to keep the dynamic link between the range of options and the table that changes sorting when what I needed is precisely the opposite. I can confirm the problem is fixed now.